# I cant understand why i get output like that

Tags: python-3.x, ip, subprocess, output, ping

I am trying to write a script that sends pings to ip's between 2 given range and tries to understand if they are available or not . I did some progress but there things that i still cant solve . For example, i get outputs twice . If you can help me it would be perfect here is my code:

```
import subprocess
ipfirst=input("1st ip:")
iplast=input("2nd ip:")
currentip=""
ip_adresses_list=[]

"""this function may be my problem because i didnt understand the response,result structure if anyone can explain this i'd be appreciated"""

def ip_checker(ip):
    response,result=subprocess.getstatusoutput("ping -c1 -w0.5 "+ip)
    if (response==0):
        print(ip,"ALIVE")
    else:
        print(ip,"NOT ALIVE")         
    return ip


""""splitting in order to increase"""

ipfirst=ipfirst.split(".")
ipfirst=list(map(int,ipfirst))
iplast=iplast.split(".")
iplast=list(map(int,iplast))


"""here while loop increases the ipfirst and appends to the list (i used just append at first but it didnt work , it only added the last ipn umber times all ip numbers like ([1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5])) and my problem may be occuring because of that structure ".copy()" """

while (iplast>ipfirst):
    ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())
    ipfirst[3] = ipfirst[3]+1
    ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())
    if (ipfirst[3]>254):
        ipfirst[3]=0
        ipfirst[2]=ipfirst[2]+1
        ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())
        if (ipfirst[2]>254):
            ipfirst[2]=0
            ipfirst[1]=ipfirst[1]+1
            ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())
            if(ipfirst[1]>254):
                ipfirst[1]=0
                ipfirst[0]=ipfirst[0]+1
                ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

"""i rearrange the list in order to get ip structure(num1.num2.num3.num4 like that) and i mixed it with ping function(ip_checker())"""

for i in ip_adresses_list:
    ip_indice1=i[0]
    ip_indice2=i[1]
    ip_indice3=i[2]
    ip_indice4=i[3]
    currentip=str(str(ip_indice1)+"."+str(ip_indice2)+"."+str(ip_indice3)+"."+str(ip_indice4))
    ip_checker(currentip)
```

and if i run this code i get and output like that icant understand why does it pings twice each ip except the first one

```
144.122.152.10 NOT ALIVE
144.122.152.11 ALIVE
144.122.152.11 ALIVE
144.122.152.12 ALIVE
144.122.152.12 ALIVE
144.122.152.13 ALIVE
144.122.152.13 ALIVE
```

Comment: You really need to add whitespace. This is so dense it's difficult to read.

Comment: The magic numbers all over the place also make this difficult to reason about, but you seem to using a extremely roundabout way of achieving your goal. The loop only needs to be like 4 lines unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your while loop that appends to the ip_address_list, it appends adds 1 appends, cycles through then appends the same ip again, adds 1 appends, so on and so forth, thats why you are getting doubles, simply moving the first append outside the loop fixed it.

also your for loop was really redundant I did the same thing in 2 lines lol

```
import subprocess
ipfirst=input("1st ip:")
iplast=input("2nd ip:")
currentip="144.122.152.13"
ip_adresses_list=[]

"""this function may be my problem because i didnt understand the response,result structure if anyone can explain this i'd be appreciated"""

def ip_checker(ip):
    response,result=subprocess.getstatusoutput("ping -c1 -w0.5 "+ip)
    if (response==0):
        print(ip,"ALIVE")
    else:
        print(ip,"NOT ALIVE")         
    return ip


""""splitting in order to increase"""

ipfirst=ipfirst.split(".")
ipfirst=list(map(int,ipfirst))
iplast=iplast.split(".")
iplast=list(map(int,iplast))


"""here while loop increases the ipfirst and appends to the list (i used just append at first but it didnt work , it only added the last ipn umber times all ip numbers like ([1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5],[1.1.1.5])) and my problem may be occuring because of that structure ".copy()" """

ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

while (iplast>ipfirst):
    ipfirst[3] = ipfirst[3]+1
    ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

    if (ipfirst[3]>254):
        ipfirst[3]=0
        ipfirst[2]=ipfirst[2]+1
        ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

        if (ipfirst[2]>254):
            ipfirst[2]=0
            ipfirst[1]=ipfirst[1]+1
            ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

            if(ipfirst[1]>254):
                ipfirst[1]=0
                ipfirst[0]=ipfirst[0]+1
                ip_adresses_list.append(ipfirst.copy())

"""i rearrange the list in order to get ip structure(num1.num2.num3.num4 like that) and i mixed it with ping function(ip_checker())"""

for ip_indice in ip_adresses_list:
    currentip=str(str(ip_indice[0])+"."+str(ip_indice[1])+"."+str(ip_indice[2])+"."+str(ip_indice[3]))
    ip_checker(currentip)
```